# Cannot alter created role

Tags: sql-server, role

I am fairly new to SQL. I use microsoft sql server management studio. I used Master database. Created a server role. But when I try to add members to the role or grant it permissions it says it doesn't exist or I might not have the permissions to do that. The role is in my server object lists so it has been created.

Update : I managed to add members to my role but I still can't grant it any permissions.

I tried logging in as sa without any luck.

I'm gonna post my detailed code and context see if anything rings a bell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What permissions does the account you are using have and what is the code you are using to add users to the role?

it should be

```
USE master
ALTER SERVER ROLE MyRole ADD MEMBER MyLogin
```

I would expect you have fallen foul to either

- omitting the `SERVER` keyword
- tried adding a database user rather than a server login to the role

Based on your comment below, it seems you are having issues with the GRANT of permissions to your server role and I would assume your code is something like:

```
CREATE SERVER ROLE MyServerRole;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON MyDatabase TO MyServerRole;
```

This will not work as you are granting database permissions to a server principal, you will need to create a role in your database and GRANT permissions to that

```
USE MyDatabase
CREATE ROLE MyDatabaseRole
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON DATABASE:: MyDatabase TO MyDatabaseRole;
```

Comment: Shoot... I did both of these mistakes -.- thank you so much. I still can't grant permissions to that server role though :/

Comment: I wrote : use master
Grant select, update
On database
To server_role

Comment: At one point, I logged in as sa to see if it would change something but it didnt so unsure

Comment: @KarianeJardin now updated

Comment: Thank you so much. I was following the teacher's code but I guess he didn't know or was confused.

Answer (score 0):

Can you find your created role with the following statement?

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.server_principals AS sp
WHERE  type = 'R';
```

If you can find it, you can use the following statement to add an user to the role:

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE [NameOfServerRole] ADD MEMBER [NameOfUser];
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and update you!

Comment: It did work thank you! I'm still unable to grant permission to that server role though.

Comment: I wrote use master
Grant select, update
On database
To server_role